# Using if condition for select query with in a select query

Tags: mysql

Here is my query

```
SELECT username, userlevel, mobile,
    IF((SELECT count(*) FROM active_users  WHERE username=a.username) AS COU > 0 ), 10, 0)
    AS status
FROM users a
```

I want to return 10 if the count is greater than 0, else I want to return 0. Is this possible.
In this I want return 4 columns username, userlevel, mobile, status and I am taking status as the parameter to classify user. If this value is classified here it will reduce the conditional statement in PHP. So I'm trying to sort out here

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a `CASE WHEN` expression:

```
SELECT a.username, a.userlevel, a.mobile,
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM active_users WHERE username = a.username) > 0
        THEN 10
        ELSE 0
    END AS status
FROM users a
```